# How can I block a pipe until a pattern match?

Tags: unix, pipe, sh, named-pipes

How can I block a pipe until a pattern is matched?
I want to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkfifo request response
while true; do # needs to send one response at a time
  nc -N -l 127.0.0.1 4000 >request <response & # send output to request pipe
  sed -u '/^$/q' <request; # block until a blank line is received
  date | tee response # send input back to the original command
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If the operations that match a pattern are blocking, cat can be used to prevent data from coming out of a named pipe until something is written to it.  cat will read data from the named pipe until EOF is written to it.

```
#!/bin/sh

mkfifo response
while true; do # send one response at a time
  cat response | nc -N -l 127.0.0.1 4000 | # pipe request out
  (
    sed -u '/^$/q' # block until a blank line is received
    date | tee response # send input back to the original command
  )
done
```